# Реализуйте функцию minmax(), которая принимает как массив чисел, так и строк, без использования Math.max(), Math.min()

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, max, min

Я новичок в JavaScript, только учусь. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Учитывая массив значений, функция minmax() должна вернуть массив, который содержит минимальное и максимальное значения в массиве, всегда с минимумом в индексе 0 и максимальным в индексе 1.
Использовать Math.max() или Math.min() нельзя.

Массив может быть списком строк в нижнем регистре вместо чисел. В этом случае min - это строка, которая будет отсортированная по алфавиту с начала, а max - строка, отсортированная по алфавиту с конца ("a" <"b", а "ab" > "aa" и т. д.).
Массивы смешанного типа (строки и числа) нас не интересуют.

```
function minmax(list) {

}
```

Примеры ожидаемого вывода:

```
console.log(minmax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));// returns [1, 5]
console.log(minmax([90, 89, 123, 3]))// returns [3, 123]
console.log(minmax(["apple", "banana", "canada"]));// returns ["apple", "canada"]
console.log(minmax([]));// returns [undefined, undefined]
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Эта... за Вас написать?

Comment: У вас ведь уже написано решение. Осталось только открыть какую-то [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) и оформить ответ )

Comment: @РустамГимранов Сортировать ради одного прохода по массиву? "Научи меня плохому" - "Ералаш"

Comment: @Igor, ваш вариант?

Comment: @РустамГимранов мой вариант - ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function minmax(list) {
  var result = [list[0], list[0]];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] < result[0])
      result[0] = list[i];
    else if (list[i] > result[1])
      result[1] = list[i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(minmax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])));// returns [1, 5]
console.log(JSON.stringify(minmax([90, 89, 123, 3])));// returns [3, 123]
console.log(JSON.stringify(minmax(["apple", "banana", "canada"])));// returns ["apple", "canada"]
console.log(minmax([]));// returns [undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: Ага, вижу. Но только что плохого в варианте с `.sort()`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Какова скорость сортировки? А перебора?

Comment: Да скорость дело третье. Просто при использовании метода `.sort()` без передачи функции сравнения, не выполняются условия задачи: `[123,3,89,90]`. Поэтому предложенный мной вариант не подходит.

Comment: @Igor я додумалась сама только до этого, но со строками не работало
```java script
var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     if (typeof list[i] === 'string') {
       result = list.sort();
     }
   }
   list.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a - b;
   });
   result.push(list[0]);
   list.sort(function(a, b) {
     return b - a;
   });
   result.push(list[0]);
   return result;
```